# I am trying to hold value of document.getElementById("image").src=UserInput +".gif"

Tags: javascript, html

first I want to hold the value of

`document.getElementById("image").src = UserInput + ".gif";`

in (var filepath) then I want to convert that value to if filepath is true or false

```
var FilePath === document.getElementById("image").src = UserInput + ".gif";

if(Filepath==true){
    #do something
}
else{  
    #print user input is wrong 
}
```

Comment: it would help if you described what you have tried so far or what particular issue you are having.

Comment: is that client side or backend ? mean are you using node js ?

Comment: it is in javascript and HTML

Comment: first I want to do document.getElementById("image").src = UserInput + ".gif"; so, when document.getElementById("image").src  holds the value of userinput +".gif". at last, I want to convert that holding value to var filepath

Comment: When do you want Filepath to be true?

Comment: I want to check file is exist or not using FilePath is true or not in javascript

Comment: `FilePath` is being set to `UserInput + ".gif"`. How do you expect assigning a string would check whether the file exists?

Answer (score 2):

send ajax request to check if file exists on your server:

```
var file_name = document.getElementById("image").src = UserInput + ".gif";
var url_to_file = "http://www.example.com/"+file_name;
$.ajax({
  url: url_to_file,
  type:'HEAD',
  error: function()
  {
    //file doesnt exist
  },
  success: function()
  {
    //file exists
  }
});
```

Its worth to mention this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD

setting `type: 'head'` in ajax request won't download file itself.

Comment: It's work perfect, thank you. I am having an issue that the error message isn't displaying on the screen

Comment: @PageTfans what do you mean ?

Comment: whenever file doesn't exist, I want to display saying file not found. the error message isn't displaying on the screen

Comment: and where you suppoust to show it ?  I think you looking for this: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_html.asp - Changing HTML Content

Comment: Here, what I want to display an alert message whenever file doesn't exist.     

error: function()
   {
    alert('data not found.');
   }

Comment: so what is the problem ?

Comment: I have figured it out another way to display the error message on the screen

Answer (score 0):

You can use the image's `load` and `error` events to detect whether the image can be loaded successfully or not.

```
var image = document.getElementById("image");
image.addEventListener("load", function() {
    # do something
});
image.addEventListener("error", function() {
    # print user input is wrong
});
image.src = UserInput + ".gif";
```